# Combine Two Collection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a 2 collection. I want to combine.

```
$a = collect([1,2,3]);
$b = collect(['a','b','c']);
```

I want that ;

```
$c = 1-a ;
```

How do I combine the two?

```
 {{ Form::select('things', $c , NULL,NULL ['id' => 'myselect']) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to combine these collections.

```
$a = collect([1,2,3]);
$b = collect(['a','b','c']);

$combined = $a->combine($b);
```

Then use `map()` method for manipulate your collection items

```
$united = $combined->map(function ($value,$key){
    return $key."-".$value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $a = collect([1,2,3]);
  $b = collect(['a','b','c']);

  $c = $a->combine($b);

  $d = $c->map(function($item, $key){
    return $item . '-' . $key;
  });
```

Comment: İt's works. Result ;
Collection;
items : array:4 
  "1" => "a"
 Okay now this collection how select2 ? display;
 I want =   1-a